# SQL and XML shaping - true\false data values used to create the XML elements

Tags: sql-server, xml

The solutions to this is eluding me and I am hoping you can help.

The data set from table [restrictions] looks like this

```
    item_uid    include    the_value
    00035061     FALSE        'AZ'
    00035061     FALSE        'CA'
    00035061     TRUE         'NC'
    00035061     TRUE         'SC'
```

The intended XML result should look like:

```
<item>
    <item_uid>00035061</item_uid>
    <restrictions>
        <inclusions>
            <include>NC</include>
            <include>SC</include>
        </inclusions>
        <exclusions>
            <exclude>AZ</exclude>
            <exclude>CA</exclude>
        </exclusions>
    </restrictions>
<item>
```

I can assemble each side seperately;

```
SELECT the_value AS 'data()'
FROM restrictions
WHERE include = TRUE AND item_uid = '00031762'
FOR XML PATH ('include'), ROOT ('inclusions')
```

And then

```
SELECT the_value AS 'data()'
FROM restrictions
WHERE include = FALSE AND item_uid = '00031762'
FOR XML PATH ('exclude'), ROOT ('exclusions')
```

but can not figure out how to generate this XML in one SQL statement.  Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You can have your queries as sub queries in the field list.

```
select D.item_uid,
       (
        select R.the_value as 'include'
        from restrictions as R
        where R.include = 1 and R.item_uid = D.item_uid
        for xml path (''), root ('inclusions'), type
       ) as 'restrictions',
       (
        select R.the_value as 'exclude'
        from restrictions as R
        where R.include = 0 and R.item_uid = D.item_uid
        for xml path (''), root ('exclusions'), type
       ) as 'restrictions'
from (select '00035061') as D(item_uid)
for xml path(''),  root('item')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88afd/1)

The `type` directive makes the query return XML instead of text.
Naming both XML columns to  `restrictions` will make them end up in the same `restrictions` element not one each.
`(select '00035061') as D(item_uid)` is only there so you can specify the `item_uid` you are looking for in one place. You probably want to replace that with a parameter instead.

Comment: Excellent.  I was close, but got confused attempting a union. Thank you.